# Laravel route get with suffix doesn't work

Tags: laravel, routes

In Laravel I have `web.php` file with these routes:

```
Route::get('/', [TasksController::class, 'gettasks']);
Route::get('/tasks/gettasks', [TasksController::class, 'gettasks']);
```

When I type my ip in the browser `xx.xxx.xx.xx` I get correct json, but when I type `xx.xxx.xx.xx/tasks/gettasks` I get `404 Not Found`.

---

when I call rout:list I see both of request:

```
GET|HEAD | / | | App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@gettasks | web 
GET|HEAD | tasks/gettasks | | App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@gettasks | web
```

---

I enabled `mod_rewrite` using command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and changed `AllowOverride` in file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` in two places. I set `AllowOverride All` then restarted the Apache server:
`service apache2 restart` but didn't help

Comment: Just went trough the routes and they are working. May be a cache issue. Just clear the route cache via ```php artisan rout:clear``` and check available route list via ```php artisan  route:list```. See the last route of this image https://ibb.co/RpvBfkd

Comment: I called `rout:clear` and now I have 404 on both of requests, when I call `rout:list` I see both of request: GET|HEAD | /                                          |      | App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@gettasks            | web 
 GET|HEAD | tasks/gettasks                             |      | App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@gettasks            | web

Comment: ok then thuis is not a issue of route then.Just rename the routes and try again.

Comment: This is on Debian, maybe server block something? What is mean rename the routes?